# How can I apply inline style to an element in abc.dust

Tags: css

How can I apply inline style to an element in abc.dust

I know how this works using external style sheet. I was wondering how to include style inline.

Comment: Give more info and examples of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the element:

```
<div class="dust" style="...">...</div>
```

or using JS/JQuery

```
$('abc.dust').css({background: '#fff'});
```